# Training error in triplet loss in facenet maked by david sandberg

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

When I implemented transfer learning in triplet loss, I receive error that is:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 160 into shape (3).

Here is implementation code.

```
python src/train_tripletloss.py --logs_base_dir 
~/lab/experiments/facenet/logs/facenet/ --models_base_dir 
~/lab/experiments/facenet/models/facenet/ --data_dir 
~/lab/experiments/noise_lfw_30_mtcnnalign_182_160 --image_size 160 --model_def 
models.inception_resnet_v1 --weight_decay 1e-4 --optimizer RMSPROP --
learning_rate 0.01 --keep_probability 0.8 --random_crop --random_flip --
pretrained_model ~/lab/experiments/facenet/model/20170512-110547/model-20170512-
110547.ckpt-250000 --people_per_batch 80 --images_per_person 2 --
gpu_memory_fraction 0.15
```

And here is all error messages

```
Running forward pass on sampled images: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/train_tripletloss.py", line 486, in 
main(parse_arguments(sys.argv[1:]))
File "src/train_tripletloss.py", line 186, in main
args.embedding_size, anchor, positive, negative, triplet_loss)
File "src/train_tripletloss.py", line 217, in train
labels_array = np.reshape(np.arange(nrof_examples),(-1,3))
File "/home/hideki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 232, in reshape
return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
File "/home/hideki/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 160 into shape (3)
```

The dataset used transfer learning is LFW dataset aligned by mtcnn and size is 160 x 160.
The dataset have 1678 directories and 3356 files.
Although I tried to changing 160 to 182 in size, program said the same error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the data you are trying to reshape does not have a label. `nrof_examples` is expected to be of shape (...,3) where the last dimension is the label ([1,0,0] for L, [0,1,0] for f, etc.) but the `nrof_examples` you give has shape (160,160).

Comment: Thank you for answering! After I change `people_per_batch` and `image_per_batch`, the program doesn't say error.